# How to make NSTableView transparent?

Tags: macos, xcode4, transparency, nstableview

I want to make transparent NSTableView.
I am using WindowController class here.
I was trying this:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
     [super windowDidLoad];
     [[self enclosingScrollView] setDrawsBackground: NO];
     [[self enclosingScrollView] setBorderType:NSNoBorder];

}

- (BOOL)isOpaque {

      return NO;
} 
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)drawRect
{
     [super drawRect: drawRect];
}
```

But when i was writing this code i can't found `enclosingScrollView` in help window.
you can see here..

[image]

Any help?? Please remember me or correct me if i am doing something wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: Got Answer..!!! I just tried this

     `[tableview setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];`
     `[tableview setHeaderView:nil];`

and its working fine..

Comment: this worked for me as well. specifically setting the background color to a clearColor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got Answer..!!! I just tried this

```
[tableview setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]]; 
[tableview setHeaderView:nil];
```

and its working fine.. – –  Snehal

Copied from comment in question, as its a bit buried...

Answer (score 8):

If you have an `NSScrollView` enclosing your `NSTableView`, you can set the scroll view's `drawsBackground` property to `NO` like this:

> yourScrollView.drawsBackground = NO;

Answer (score 5):

If your app needs to display a **transparent table view**, set the background color of the table view to be clear and set the enclosing scroll view to not draw its background. The following code snippet shows one way to display a transparent table:

Swift:

```
yourTableView.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
yourTableView.enclosingScrollView?.drawsBackground = false
```

Objective-C

```
[theTableView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor];
[[theTableView enclosingScrollView] setDrawsBackground:NO];
```

[Apple - Modifying a Table’s Visual Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/VisualAttributes/VisualAttributes.html)